# how to add counter to GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, counter

I wish to add counters to my buttons I also want to learn how to set each counter so as I may have it open a file on my computer once it reaches the set number of counts I set in the

```
package layout;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class BoxLayoutDemo {
    public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {
        pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    addAButton("Section 1", pane);
    addAButton("Section 2", pane);
    addAButton("Section 3", pane);
    addAButton("Section 4", pane);
    addAButton("Section 5", pane);
    addAButton("Section 6", pane);
    addAButton("Section 7", pane);
    addAButton("Section 8", pane);
    addAButton("Section 9", pane);
}

private static void addAButton(String text, Container container) {
    JButton button = new JButton(text);
    button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    container.add(button);
}


private static void createAndShowGUI() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Counter");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
`
```

Please help I am a noob and it has taken me weeks to find how to do this much.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What is your specific question?  *"once it reaches the set number of counts I set in the.."*  The what?  Until you find a forum with psychic people to reply, I would suggest carefully rereading your post, to a friend if you can, to make sure it makes sense before posting.

Comment: BTW  `addAButton("Section 1", pane); .. addAButton("Section 9", pane);` Doing GUI programming before you have mastered loops is a strange way of going about things.  It seems like trying to paint the gutters on a house for which there are no foundations, no structure.

Comment: Sorry I mean when it reaches a set count number it will then open one of 6 .exe files that I all ready have.

Comment: @user1359327 : It would be wise, that you interact with the people who provide answers to your thread, so that  they be able to understand the situation better, as to where exactly you are stuck, and how exactly to help you, to MOVE ON :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have added a button to a container, but you haven't added any Listeners to that button - so it won't perform any action by clicking it...

```
private static void addAButton(String text, Container container) { 
    JButton button = new JButton(text); 
    button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT); 
    container.add(button); 
}
```

So you need to add an ActionListener to your button, and let it increment a counter. In your action listener, you can add a counter.

The new code could look something like this:

```
private static void addAButton(String text, Container container) { 
    JButton button = new JButton(text); 
    button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT); 
    button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    container.add(button);
} 

class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    int numClicks;
    static int buttonClicks = 0;
    ButtonListener() {
        numClicks = 0;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        buttonClicks++;
        numClicks++;
        // do some action
    }
    public int getNumClicks() { return numClicks; }
    static public int getButtonClicks() { return buttonClicks; }
}
```

In this example, I've added a two methods:
1) getNumClicks(): get number of clicks in this ButtonListener instance (so long as you add a new ButtonListener to each button, this will be unique for each button.)
2) getButtonClicks(): get number of clicks across all instances

A better way, would be to extend JButton to create your own custom button, then you could add those methods to the button itself rather than the ButtonListener.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of times a button is pressed, then you need an ActionListener. Here is an example of such:

```
public class IListen implements ActionListener
{
    int hits = 0;
    public IListen()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("hello!");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(200,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
         JButton source = e.getSource();
         if(source == button)
            hits++;

        System.out.println("you hit my button "+hits+" times!");
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new IListen();
    }
}
```

I havent compiled that myself so sorry if there are syntax errors, hopefully this will help you out and widen your programming abilities.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know to do what you want is [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). If it took you weeks to get that much done it would be very beneficial for you to read the tutorial thoroughly.